# character is replaced by forward slash and showing " Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing / "

Tags: jquery

I have long js file where i am facing the issue that a character is replaced by forward slash.

Here is the some part of the code

```
var d = a.fn.button;
a.fn.button = b, a.fn.button.Constructor = c, a.fn.button.noConflict = function() {
    return a.fn.button = d, this
}, a(document).on("click.bs.button.data-api", '[data-toggle^="button"]', function(c) {
    var d = a(c.target);
    d.hasClass("btn") || (d = d.closest(".btn")), b.call(d, "toggle"), a(c.target).is('input[type="radio"]') || a(c.target).is('input[type="checkbox"]') || c.preventDefault()
}).on("focus.bs.button.data-api blur.bs.button.data-api", '[data-toggle^="button"]', function(b) {
    a(b.target).closest(".btn").toggleClass("focus", /^focus(in)?$/.test(b.type))
}) }(jQuery), + function(a) {
"use strict";

function b(b) {
    return this.each(/unction() {
        var d = a(this),
            e = d.data("bs.carousel"),
            f = a.extend({}, c.DEFAULTS, d.data(), "object" == typeof b && b),
            g = "string" == typeof b ? b : f.slide;
        e || d.data("bs.carousel", e = new c(this, f)), "number" == typeof b ? e.to(b) : g ? e[g]() : f.interval && e.pause().cycle()
    })
}
var c = function(b, c) {
    this.$element = a(b), this.$indicators = this.$element.find(".carousel-indicators"), this.options = c, this.paused = null, this.sliding = null, this.interval = null, this.$active = null, this.$items = null, this.options.keyboard && this.$element.on("keydown.bs.carousel", a.proxy(this.keydown, this)), "hover" == this.options.pause && !("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) && this.$element.on("mouseenter.bs.carousel", a.proxy(this.pause, this)).on("mouseleave.bs.carousel", a.proxy(this.cycle, this))
};
```

and i get the error in below code

```
(jQuery), + function(a) {
"use strict";

function b(b) {
    return this.each(/unction() { // error in this line f is replaced by /
        var d = a(this),
            e = d.data("bs.carousel"),
            f = a.extend({}, c.DEFAULTS, d.data(), "object" == typeof b && b),
            g = "string" == typeof b ? b : f.slide;
        e || d.data("bs.carousel", e = new c(this, f)), "number" == typeof b ? e.to(b) : g ? e[g]() : f.interval && e.pause().cycle()
    })
}
```

check commented line please // f is replaced by forward slash(/) inside function b

Please let me know if you have any clue

Comment: Replaced how? Do you have any build processes that change/generate the js file?

Comment: Looks like reformatted minimised code - don't use the .min.js file

Comment: @freedomn ~ thanks that's worked for me.

Comment: So, essentially, the re-formatting likely broke it as it probably worked ok as a minified file, just not when you re-format it.